# NestedScrollView and WebView

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I have got NestedScrollView with WebView inside and I am using collapsing toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

When I load content of webView and content have got more height than screen, it works great. Toolbar is hiden/show on scroll.

Second situation is when content of webview is small.
When I hang `NestedScrollView` at bottom and drag to top, Toolbar hiden and drag to bottom Toolbar shown.

When I trying drag from `WebView` it isn't work, view is still in the same place.

Any idea how to fix this.

Don't allow hide Toolbar when content of `WebView` is too small or disable scroll at `WebView`

Comment: which version of the support design library are you using? 23.0.0 or an older version?